# Cannot resolve symbol TBRManager in smack 4.2 lib in Android?

Tags: android, smack

When i was used smack-im-4.2.0-beta3-SNAPSHOT.jar lib in my project its work fine with TBRManager class but now i have used smack 4.2 lib instead of smack beta-4.2 lib. after that changed the lib that issue will be occurs please help. should i need to implement other smack lib ?

here's my code

```
            TBRManager tbrManager = TBRManager.getInstanceFor(xmppConnection);
            TBRTokens tbrTokens = tbrManager.getTokens();
            String accessToken = tbrTokens.getAccessToken();
            String refreshToken = tbrTokens.getRefreshToken();
```

Comment: Please provide details about the specific error. What should happen and what are you getting ?

Comment: TBRManager class available in smack-im-4.2.0-beta3-SNAPSHOT.jar library but after the replace the lib  smack-im-4.2.0-beta3-SNAPSHOT.jar to smack-im-4.2.0.jar i have fetching this issue TBRManager class not found in smack 4.2.0 lib.what is different between smack-im-4.2.0.jar and smack-im-4.2.0-beta3-SNAPSHOT.jar ?